# How to use group by for multiple tables using multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Below is my Oracle sql query

```
Select   ELP_DEALER.DEALER,
         ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK.Entire_Record
From     ELP_DEALER,
         ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK
Where    ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK.Dealer_Id = ELP_DEALER.DEALER_ID
         And ELP_DEALER.Dealer In ( 'CABC', 'IKBC', 'CITI', 'GNHW', '0062' )
Group By ELP_DEALER.Dealer
```

Here I want the ENTIRE_RECORD field only Single record based on DEALER like CABC,IKBC. Can any one help me on this please

Sample table

This is the normal out put

```
DEALER   ENTIRE_RECORD
0068      xyz

0068      abc

cabc      pqr

cabc      npq
```

Expceted Output should be

```
DEALER ENTIRE_RECORD
0068   anyoftheonerecord
cabc   anyoftheonerecord
```

Comment: I think you need sample data and desired results.

Comment: Ok, you want "a single row per `DEALER`", so, what value should the other columns show?

Comment: yes Lamak thank you so much exactly

Comment: Other column is not mandatory

Comment: @Lamak I want a single row per Dealer that should display Entire_record column result set

Comment: You need to explain what row to show if multiple are available.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding the issue. Assume that you have a row where `DEALER` is `'CABC'` and `Entire_Record` is `'A'`, you have another row where `DEALER` is `'CABC'` and `Entire_Record` is `'B'`. Since you want **a single** value for `DEALER`, which value for `Entire_Record` do you want?. Please, explain clearly your requirements

Comment: @Lamak My requirement is for CABC there are no.of Records so for CABC I want only single record like that for GNHW I want only one record and that record should display ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK.Entire_Record data

Comment: Simply show sample records from required table(s) and sample records in your desired output.No need to post original data..And the answer  here will be ready..

Comment: @KaushikNayak I edited and added sample records so can you please provide the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select   ELP_DEALER.DEALER,
         MAX(ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK.Entire_Record) ENTIRE_RECORD
From     ELP_DEALER,
         ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK
Where    ELP_DEALER_RECON_WRK.Dealer_Id = ELP_DEALER.DEALER_ID
         And ELP_DEALER.Dealer In ( 'CABC', 'IKBC', 'CITI', 'GNHW', '0062' )
Group By ELP_DEALER.Dealer
```

Comment: Thank you soooooooo much Kaushik you saved me